# I Imported a Javax package, but cannot use any of its methods

Tags: java, swing, jframe

So I was just playing around and imported javax swing to practice with GUIs. For some reason it will not let me use any of the methods. I know im being dumb but cannot for the life of me figure out why. I just want to understand and avoid this problem in the future.

[image: Here is the screenshot from Eclipse]

Comment: Your statements are not inside a method.  They need to be inside a method, such as the `main` method that you closed above your `frame` statements.

Comment: wow. I just looked at it. I think its time for coffee.

Comment: It happens :) you'll learn from it.

Comment: Post code (& text) as text, not screenshots.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because author pasted a screenshot-of-code instead of code-as-text